# Can tf-idf values be added to find document similarity?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

I am working with tf-idf and text classification to rank words in documents. I was wondering if adding tf-idf values for respective words can be used to predict the nearest match for a new document. What I mean by this is:

```
Suppose I had the following tf-idf values for certain words (hypothetical):

    word   Category 1   Category 2   Category 3
    x      0.3          0.6          0.2
    y      0.8          0.4          0.1
    z      0.2          0.5          0.7
```

The categories in this case are very long documents consisting of all of the documents in a certain category combined, this reduces the corpus size from thousands to just 10 in my case. It's also worth noting that I am using sublinear TF in order to reduce the effects of very frequent terms.

If I had a new document that had the words "x y" in it, what I was thinking of is adding up the tf-idf values for those words in each category and whichever category has the greatest sum would be the nearest match to the new document. In this case, the sum for category 1 would be 1.1, 1.0 for category 2, and 0.3 for category 3, therefore the nearest match to the new document is category 1. I was also wondering if this "algorithm" already exists and has a name.

I tried this on some test data and it predicts it accurately 86% of the time. And it seems to make more sense than using a LogisticRegression. So, is this a valid algorithm?

Comment: Could you clarify how you got the categories? How do they differ? Are they on different topics?

Comment: @amdex My data is job descriptions that have been pre-assigned to one of 10 job titles. The titles are the categories.